# Replicating Data from Azure (PostgreSQL) using IICS

Tags: azure, database-replication, iics

Using IICS, is it possible to replicate data to a data warehouse (local, Oracle) from Azure (PostgreSQL), without installing a secure agent on the Azure instance?

I haven't tried anything yet, just trying to understand my options.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using the PostgreSQL connection type.
The secure agent can be install on any computer.  Once installed and configured, there are 2 connecters for PostgreSQL sources, "PostgreSQL" and "PostgreSQL CDC".